# In AngularJS, how do I access a component's scope during HTML template instantiation?

Tags: angularjs, typescript

So without explaining to me why this is a bad idea, I'm hoping someone can advise me on how to achieve the following.

Using AngularJS 1.7, Typescript and MobX, I have a view controller that has a reference to the controller of a child component.

```
class ViewCtrl {
  @observable myChildCtrl: IChildCtrl;
```

Here's what I want to write in the HTML (although I suspect ng-init isn't it):

```
<child-ctrl ng-init="$ctrl.myChildCtrl = **myChildCtrl's $ctrl**"></child-ctrl>
```

That is, $ctrl refers to ViewCtrl. The childCtrl has a $scope with its own $ctrl, which is what I want to inject into the parent. And actually, I want to be able to bind this so that if there's an ng-if in the mix and child-ctrl goes from included to not included, myChildCtrl would also be set to null.

I have a slightly hacky solution for this, but I'm wondering if there's a cleaner way.

---

Incidentally my solution was to create a base class for components containing the following:

```
  private $postLink() {
    this.preFlight();
    runInAction(() => {
      this.target[this.property] = this.$scope['$ctrl'];
    });
  }

  private $onDestroy() {
    this.preFlight();
    runInAction(() => {
      this.target[this.property] = null;
    });
  }
```

And then it's instantiated like this:

```
<child-ctrl target="$ctrl" property="myChildCtrl">
```

So this works, and I think it's pretty robust - just wondering if this can be done using attribute directives instead.

Comment: One of my concerns with this question is how to do it robustly, avoiding memory leaks. When an object is assigned to a parent scope from a child scope, the reference needs to be nulled when the child scope is destroyed. In addition the `ng-if` directive creates an inherited scope that is created and destroyed when its expression changes.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I was concerned about that too. Anyway, I posted my solution as an edit to my OP. Would prefer that this could be done with an attribute directive, but would been to hook into $postLink and $onDestroy somehow.

Comment: Look at the [`ng-ref`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRef) directive.